# Add "Blank" to lightning:recordForm

Tags: lightning-aura-components, page-layout

I am trying to replicate a page layout by using `lightning:recordForm`.
I can't seem to be able to add a blank space when i don't have an even number of fields, and it causes the last field to spread out.

[image]

That's the component:

```
<c:CollapsibleSection title="{!v.title}">
    <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters_small full cols-2 forcePageBlockSectionRow">
        <div class="slds-col">
        <lightning:recordForm
            recordId="{!v.recordId}"
            objectApiName="{!v.sObjectName}"
            columns="2"
            fields="{!v.fieldsList}"
            mode="{!v.viewMode}" />
        </div>
    </div>
</c:CollapsibleSection>
```

That's CollapsibleSection.cmp:

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="title" type="String"/>
    <div class="slds-section slds-is-open" aura:id="collapsibleSectionContainer">
        <h3 class="slds-section__title slds-theme_shade">
            <lightning:buttonStateful labelWhenOff="{!v.title}"
                                        labelWhenOn="{!v.title}"
                                        iconNameWhenOff="utility:chevrondown"
                                        iconNameWhenOn="utility:chevronright"
                                        onclick="{!c.handleSectionHeaderClick}"
                                        class="slds-section__title-action" />
        </h3>
        <div class="slds-section__content" >
            {!v.body}
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Do you have an idea how can i add a blank space, just like in a page layout? 
i tried to add a `null` value or `''` to `fieldsList` but got an error. this is the code that adds it:

```
getPageFromFieldSet: function(component, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getPageFromFieldSet");

        var fieldSourceApiName = component.get("v.fieldSourceApiName");
        var recordId = component.get("v.recordId");

        var actionParams = {
            "recordId" : recordId,
            "fieldSourceApiName" : fieldSourceApiName
        };

        action.setParams(actionParams);
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            debugger;
            if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
                var fieldsList = response.getReturnValue();
                component.set("v.fieldsList", fieldsList);

                if(component.get("v.fieldsList").length % 2 != 0) {
                    var a = component.get("v.fieldsList");
                    a.push('');
                    component.set("v.fieldsList",a);
                }
            }
        });
```

That's the error:

```
Expected name to include an expression after the object API name: Account. is invalid
```

When i tried to show a list like this, it worked:

```
<aura:attribute name="fieldsListTwo" type="String[]" access="private" default="Name,Id,Billing_Account_ID__c,''"/>
```

But by code, adding that doesn't.

Comment: for more 'control' over how the rows and columns are displayed i would recommend using the recordEditForm instead.

Comment: recordEditForm is not behaving and looking exactly like a standard page layout, therefore i cant use it

Comment: With moving from view to edit modes like here? having save buttons out of the box? the pencil icon? i need to replicate the exact same behavior like layout. can you point me to a document or example please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92111/discussion-between-dana-griff-and-glls).

Comment: Instead of trying to add `null` or `''`, you can add a field that cannot be edited like `CreatedDate` and you will get the layout you are looking for.

Comment: @javanoob But then i will have a field i don't want shown, instead of blank space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally - I would suggest you use a [RecordEditForm](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/example) component for your particular use case, however, if you have an absolute requirement of keeping a certain layout/behavior that resembles the recordLAyout component, then there are 2 alternatives:

1. Go full custom, this implies using salesforce SLDS Blueprints to create your form and absically coding it from scratch (which is what you seem to be wanting to avoid and is completely understandable)
2. CSS hack the form to limit the width, however, this is strongly ill advised, since it may affect other form input's that might share the sleector you specify and is generally considered  bad practice.

This [sample gist](https://gist.github.com/gminero/0b55cba37dd09644cb36b5a95c62b2b2) has the basic layout for customizing a field adapted from the slds blueprints where you can build upon, in the background it uses a recordEditform which is hidden, from which you can fetch whatever field values from the recordId specified on the recordEditform layout.

So, you will have to outweight the pro's and cons of each approach, or simply live with the fact that a non-pair field will expand to the full width of the form component you have.